# scp ing to several destinations with one password without public keys

Tags: authentication, scp

I hope this isn't a duplicate question, I did do some research on this before posting.

I have several directories locally, which I need to `scp` over to several remote machines (1 dir per remote machine). Currently, this is how I do it:

```
scp d1 remote1:/location1/ && scp2 d2 remote2:/location2/ && ...
```

The problem is that `scp` asks me for my password for each machine. Normally, I would solve this by adding my local public key to the remote machines, but since there are about 100 of these remote machines, I don't feel like that is a very attractive option.

Is there a way by which I could supply my password at most once to scp all these dirs to all the remote machines?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not too worried about exposing your password in plaintext on your local machine check out http://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp and -pw flag